# show and hide the description in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have list of item which is generated in dynamically.views-row-1,views-row-2,views-row-3, etc.inside it has `contactTitle` and `contactDesc`.

By default I want to show only the first description and want to hide other description.If I click the `ContactTitle` of `views-rows-2` I want to show `contactDesc` of 2nd views and hide other views `contactDesc` and vice versa.

If I click first title it shows all desc.I want to show the contentDesc of the related views and hide other views desc

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
    $('.contactDesc').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: try `$(this).find('contactDesc').show();`

Comment: i have done with toggle. check this: https://jsfiddle.net/hL1g9ppy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your JS to this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z8q19d7/5/)

Comment: Is it possible in slideUp or toggle

Comment: If title 3 is clicked again it slide up and slide down now.In this case I want to stop slide up for 3rd desc

Answer (score 1):

use **toggle** try this:

demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL1g9ppy/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
    $(this).next( ".contactDesc").toggle( "fast", function() {
  });
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the element triggering the event and apply your handler to the next following element.

Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.contactTitle').click(function() {
    $('.contactDesc').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle">
    Title 1
  </div>
  <div style="display: block;" class="contactDesc">
    desc 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle">
    Title 2
  </div>
  <div class="contactDesc">
    Desc 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle">
    Title 3
  </div>
  <div class="contactDesc">
    Desc 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row .contactTitle').click(function(){
    $('.contactDesc').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.contactDesc').show();
  });
});
```

[Demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko9vkt89/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
      $('.contactDesc').hide();
      $(this).next().show();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve clicked detail show and other to hide you need to update your js to following.

```
$(function() {
  $('.contactTitle').on('click', function() {
    var currentTitle = $(this);
    $('.contactDesc').hide();
    currentTitle.next('.contactDesc').show();
  })
})
```

What I have done is saved clicked title in variable and hidden all description div's then only show the clicked next description div. Hope this helps

Comment: can you give fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL1g9ppy/3/)

```
  $('.contactTitle').click(function() {
    var description = $(this).next();
    var descriptionList = $('.contactTitle').next();

    for(var i = 0; i < descriptionList.length; i++) {
        var element = $(descriptionList[i]);

        if (element.is(description)) {
        element.toggleClass('contactDesc');
      } else {
        element.addClass('contactDesc');
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this jquery snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
      $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
        $('.contactDesc').hide();
        $(this).next('.contactDesc').show();
      });
    });
```

Here's a running example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){
   $('.contactDesc').hide();
    $(this).next('.contactDesc').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```